# what is the maximum number of roots of quadratic function with 3 variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, roots, quadratic-forms

Given the general quadratic form with $3$ variables $(x,y,z):ax^2 + by^2 +cz^2 + dxy + eyz +fzx + gx + hy + iz = 0$ satisfies $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

I would like to ask what is the maximum number of roots of the provided equation.

Thanks in advance

It seems obvious from the first few comments that the set of solution which is the intersection between the two surface is infinity.

If adding 2 constraints: 1. the solutions are real numbers and 2. any 4 points in the set of solution can not lie on the same plane, what is maximum number of solutions?

Comment: Did you mean to have a constant term in the first form? The answer's the same in either case, but that form is not as general as it could be.

Comment: a,b,c,d,...i are constants

Comment: I meant an entire constant term, $+j$.

Comment: I guess adding a constant term j inside would not make any different since x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1

Comment: No. You are confused.

Comment: j = jx^2 + jy^2 + jz^2, then j can be absorbed by a,b,c. I was confused by your first comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question could be written more precisely: when you say "satisfies $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$", I assume you mean that you are looking for simulateneous solutions of *both* equations.

Anyway, the answer is that such a system of equations can have infinitely many solutions. Geometrically, each equation defines a surface in 3-dimensional space, and their common solutions are the intersection points of those surfaces.

If we are talking about real-number solutions, then your second equation defines the unit sphere, and it's not hard to visualise another surface (the solution set of the first equation) intersecting it in a curve, say.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we only consider real number solution, and add a constrain that any 4 points can not lie on the same surface, what is the maximum number of solutions that satisfy these two additional condition? I encounter this on WolframMathWorld : A curve in which two arbitrary quadratic surfaces in arbitrary positions intersect cannot meet any plane in more than four points (Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen 1999, p. 24).

Comment: I don't really understand the follow-up question. Any 4 of which points cannot lie on the same surface? The quote from Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen is correct, but that is describing a situation in which _three_ surfaces are intersecting: two quadric surfaces and a plane.

Answer (score 1):

There could be infinitely many solutions to those two equations. Let $a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=0$ and let $i=1$.

Then the first equation becomes $z=0$, which is the $xy$-plane, and that intersects the unit sphere in the unit circle.